# What browsers does autoprefixer target for 'last 2 versions'?

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, autoprefixer

Running a autoprefixer task though grunt with 'last 2 version' under browsers. What browsers is this targeting? I would assume this means the last 2 versions of all browsers but I can't see any -moz prefixes in the CSS output.

```
grunt.config('autoprefixer', {
    options: {
      browsers: ['last 2 version']
    },
    dist: {
      expand: true,
      src: '/styles/app.css'
    }
  });
```

Comment: "but I can't see any -moz prefixes in the CSS output" That depends on what properties you're using. Which properties are you expecting to see the prefix on?

Comment: Anything! -moz is not showing up anywhere. Examples are transition, transition-delay, animation, @keyframes.

Comment: None of the examples you mention have required prefixes since [Firefox 16](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/16.0/releasenotes). It might just be that the properties you're using simply haven't required prefixes for quite some time. Off the top of my head the only property that still requires a prefix is `-moz-box-sizing`, which was only unprefixed in Firefox 30 a couple of months back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Last 2 versions' means - support latest stable version (not beta or nightly builds) and one version earlier.

Answer (score 4):

On Browserlist you can see, which browsers are currently meant by 'last 2 versions' [Link](http://browserl.ist/?q=last%202%20versions).

Answer (score 0):

It should probably be `'last 2 versions'`. (You're missing and `s` at the end!)

When I tried `'last 2 versions'`, and then compared the resulting CSS file with the one from `'last 50 versions'`, the result was identical, so the number of versions doesn't seem to matter (much).